# Unable to do sort on arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of jquery objects by text.

```
var $divs = $("#"+menu +"> div");
var numOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).text() > $(b).text();
});
$("#"+menu).html(numOrderedDivs);
```

However I am seeing no changes

[image]

[image]

Comment: so what is text() returning? Small sample of HTML would go a long away in helping us help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [**String.localeCompare**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) in your sort:

```
var $divs = $("#"+menu +"> div");
var numOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).text().localeComrate($(b).text());
});
$("#"+menu).html(numOrderedDivs);
```

It:

> ... returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before or
>   after or is the same as the given string in sort order

it also supports various [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Parameters) for comparisons which are quite handy.

Also [**`Array.sort`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) works with a comparer function which return value should be an integer as per the docs:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```

and not a boolean like you have here: `return $(a).text() > $(b).text();`

`localeCompare` does that for you when used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ".localeCompare" for sorting strings

```
var numOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text()) // for sorting in increasing order
});
```